# Document library workflow that copies a document from one library to another doesn't overwrite

Tags: workflow, document-library, copy-item

We have written a simple workflow that when minutes of a meeting have been approved they are copied to a more public document library for a wider audience to see.

It goes like this:
If current item:approved minutes = Yes
Copy document in current item to Published Committee Minutes
Go to End of Workflow

Set to activate on when the document is changed.

It works great but I asked the question "will there ever be a situation where a document has been approved, and all of sudden the original needs to be changed".  The answer was rarely but it does happen.

So I've done some testing.  Once my document has been copied to the target, and I go edit the source document, the workflow runs again.  No new version of the file gets copied to the target library.

When I delete the file from the target document and then make a change to the source document it does copy.

Is this a feature or should I be adding an "if exist condition" to the workflow to delete the target file first so the user won't have to remember to manually delete the file first before they edit the target?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily fixable. In your workflow, right click on the copy item action and change the Overwrite value to Yes, as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Eric - works like a charm.  Adding it to the toolbox.